# jQuery form submission is returning false instead of waiting for server response

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a jQuery form which sends data to my server after validating. The server sends a response and then my site processes the returned information. Here's the javascript in question:

```
$("#signup").on('submit', function(e){
          var isvalidate = $("#signup").valid();
          if(isvalidate)
          {
            var json =  $('#signup').serialize();

            var theEmail = $('#signup #inputEmail').val();

            //Hide step 1 modal
            $('#stepOneSignup').modal('hide');

            //Open processing modal
            $('#processingModal').modal();

            $.post('http://localhost:5000/agm/saveNewUser/', json, function( data ) {
              alert('returned some data');
              if(data === "Success"){
                //Hide processing modal
                $('#processingModal').modal('hide');

              }else if(data === "UserExists"){
                $('#processingModal').modal('hide');
                $('#duplicateEmail').modal();
              }
            });
          }else{
            return false;
          }
      });
```

I can see in my server log that the `$.post(http://localhost...)` is posting just fine. My server is processing the form information (which takes a couple of seconds) but before it gets a chance to send a response my form redirects my browser to:

```
http://localhost:8888/?firtName=whateverinfoIputintheform&lastName=yeahyeahyeah
```

I never get an `alert('returned some data');`.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: remove the else part for validation that is not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `return false`, in any case, to prevent the **default post-back**:

```
$("#signup").on('submit', function(e){
    var isvalidate = $("#signup").valid();
    if(isvalidate)
    {
        ...
    }
    return false;
});
```

It is causing the ajax post request but can not process it's response because the default post-back causes before the ajax post's response is received.

Comment: Beauty! That got it working. Cheers, will accept in a sec when it lets me.

Comment: @Jascination: Good to know. Please see I have updated my code to make it more efficient and easy t understand.

Answer (score 3):

I think your ajax call is asynchronous. Try doing something link this:
Replace your ajax call with this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/agm/saveNewUser/',
  data: json,
  dataType: 'text',
  async: 'false',
  success: function(){
    alert('returned some data');
              if(data === "Success"){
                //Hide processing modal
                $('#processingModal').modal('hide');

              }else if(data === "UserExists"){
                $('#processingModal').modal('hide');
                $('#duplicateEmail').modal();
              }
  }

});
```

and then

```
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.post()` is an ajax method. The browser will not wait for the response and will keep on working as if the a server request was never made.

Comment: I see. What's a better alternative?

Comment: @Jascination Explain in the question what you want to do exactly. Better that you put all code in fiddle. If not at least provide HTML also.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.post('http://localhost:5000/agm/saveNewUser/', json, function( data ) {
        ...
    }).done(function(){
         return true;
    });
```